# No Sound from Front Headphone Ports

Tags: sound, 16.04, alsa, headphones

My Front Headphone port has stopped working on its own recently as in no sound is coming from them. It was working fine till last week after I applied some fix I found on Google. I am sorry but I don't remember what exactly I did but it involved me having to run alsamixer on every reboot to fix the headphone volume.

And now even after I fix the volume using alsamixer, there is no sound coming from the front ports. Back ports are working fine though. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help? I am very much confused on how to troubleshoot or from where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reset `alsactl` using this command and it worked. There's no need to reinstall anything.

```
sudo alsactl restore
```

Note: If you see `Device or resource busy`, login to a tty(`Ctrl+Alt+F6` or `Ctrl+Alt+F7`) and run the command at there.

**Edit:**

It seems that I mistakenly assumed that the sound was coming from my headphone. My headphone still didn't work.

This time I tried this:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
hdajackretask
```

In the new window, select the correct codec at the top. Click "show unconnected pins. Click "override" on each unconnected pins and choose "Headphone" for every pins that have this choice(don't change connected pins). Click "Install boot override" and then reboot. Now it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This worked-out for me.
In the ‘Terminal’ write `alsamixer`

In 'AlsaMixer' select Headphone using the side-arrows keys in Keyboard.

Now press `m` in Keyboard (mouse dose not work here) to Unmute the Headphone. ( When the Headphone is mute you can see in the column it shows `MM`, and after you unmute the Headphone, it will show `OO`) 
Press up-down arrow keys to control sound in your Headphone.
Now to save the configuration run this command:
`sudo alsactl store`
So the next time you open your pc, it will boot-up with that config.

Answer (score 0):

- Try clearing your modifications by reinstalling ALSA:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base libasound2-data libasound2-plugins libasound2 libpulse0 pulseaudio
  ```
- For sound troubleshooting instructions follow:

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting