# Cant hear from front Headphone, except in audacity

Tags: sound, 19.10, headphones

My rear headphone ports work normally, however when I try to use the front one, it is muted, no sound. I tried searching for the problem and almost everywhere it was said to use ALSA to unmute the headphone option, [like this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786769/no-sound-from-front-headphone-ports) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034166/no-sound-in-headphone-from-front-panel-audio-port-in-ubuntu-18-04), I tried that, and still no sound.

I started to think the problem was with my jack, but when I was messing with audacity, the sound from the program came, but only from audacity. So is there a way to make that sound works on all programs not only audacity?

[My alsa-info](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b8ad9ce8f0f98a7160e4b467a899dee09d8ec92)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) it says that when dual-booting, you have to turn on the Realtek devices. It was off, because when it was on, the front panel didn't work, even for windows.

I had to go into the bios settings and change my front audio jack from HDAudio to AC97, go to windows, make sure that the audio works with the Realtek device on, then booting into Linux and finally running this command `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ;`. 
After that my audio works fine!

Comment: for me, just the command `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ;` was enough