# Front Headphone Port Has No Sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, headphones

I have read answers from these posts, but none of these solutions worked for me.

- [No Sound from Front Headphone Ports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786769/no-sound-from-front-headphone-ports)
- [Front headphone jack not being recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913659/front-headphone-jack-not-being-recognized)
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=329281&start=40

**Problem:** The front headphone jack does not work. Oddly, HDMI speaker and back headphone Jack has no issue.

**Specs:**

- Z590 AORUS PRO AX Motherboard
- Realtek ALC4080 codec

When I type the command `hdajackretask`, it shows this page. Oddly, I can only select the HDMI codec option. I found it strange that there is no Realtek ALC4080 option.

[image: hdajackretask result]

Another weird thing is that the output device recognized headphones when I plugged them in. When I play music, I can see the bars below Output Device move, but there is no sound coming out of the headphone.

[image: sound setting]

Also, using this command, `aplay -D plughw:1,1 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav` worked and managed to play that sound.

Any help is appreciated, got stuck on this for 3 days straight :(

Comment: same problem here, did you find any answers?

Comment: related question on Arch: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681277/front-panel-not-working-alc-4080-archlinux

Comment: possibly relevant: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/issues/189